# What type should my list contain?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, odata

I have this query

```
List<int> AuctionIds = 
   (from a in _auctionContext.Auctions
    where a.AuctionEventId == auction.AuctionEventId
    select new { a.Id }).ToList();
```

But I receive a compile error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'
```

What type should AuctionIds be?

**EDIT**

The AuctionIds field is in fact in another class (a model class) so I can't just use var.  I can't believe Jon Skeet hasn't answered this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding an anonymous object to a `List<int>`..
If you were to do it the way you had it.. I would use the `var` keyword..

```
var AuctionIds = 
       (from a in _auctionContext.Auctions
        where a.AuctionEventId == auction.AuctionEventId
        select new{Id = a.Id}).ToList();
```

Reason is I don't know what type an anonymous object is.. but the compiler should be able to handle it.

**EDIT:**

Eh, about creating a `AuctionIDModel` class?

```
 public class AuctionIDModel
    {
       int Id{get;set;}
    }

    List<AuctionIDModel> AuctionIds = 
           (from a in _auctionContext.Auctions
            where a.AuctionEventId == auction.AuctionEventId
            select new AuctionIDModel{Id = a.Id}).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't want to use var because I have the AuctionIds field in another class actually.

Comment: mmn.. the only other way I can think of is create a Model to store your data. And add that Model object to your list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
List<int> AuctionIds = _auctionContext.Auctions
    .Where(a => a.AuctionEventId == auction.AuctionEventId)
    .Select(a => a.Id)
    .ToList();
```